# how to hold 2 peak of a signal simulink matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

How to combine two crossing in simulink. 
I have model that becomes true when value cross to 10(falling). I want to combine it every 2nd count.

Input is as below
[image: Input]

Desired output
[image: desired output]

Current Model
[image: Current Model]

Comment: Show your [mcve] as searchable, copyable text in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much the same question as was asked a few days ago -- [how to detect 2nd crossing to point simulink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844176/how-to-detect-2nd-crossing-to-point-simulink) -- is it a school assignment?

The same model as was used in the answer to that question, with some of the parameters changed, can be used to answer this question.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This runs perfectly